# Docker - ENTRYPOINT script causes a reboot

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose

I'm relatively new to Docker - I'm trying to build a system to run a Symfony 4 app, comprising of PHP-FPM, nginx and MySQL.

Everything works as it should except one thing. When the PHP-FPM container boots, I want to run:

```
#!/bin/bash
composer install
bin/console doctrine:database:create --if-not-exists
bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force
bin/console doctrine:fixtures:load --no-interaction
```

I created a script with these commands in and then edited my DockerFile as follows:

```
COPY ./docker/php/startup.sh /usr/local/bin/startup.sh
RUN ["chmod", "+x", "/usr/local/bin/startup.sh"]
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/startup.sh"]
```

The issue I'm having is that when I run `docker-compose build` and then `docker-compose up`, I can see the script runs, but something in it causes the container to fail and restart itself - the script then runs again, and the cycle continues. The docker-compose.yml has `restart: unless-stopped` specified by the way.

I wondered if one of the commands was exiting with a non zero code, so tried to add `exit 0` to the end of the script, but to no avail.

Am I doing something daft? To be clear, I want this script to run automatically on the first boot of the container (it's fine if it runs every boot for what it's worth, not just *the very first* time).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint

When you define entrypoint to your script. It runs it and after that it ends that means entrypoint is done.(so script executes no errors )

So you need to specify your entrypoint to php-fpm or even sleep will fix this.

Comment: Ending the ENTRYPOINT script with `exec "$@"` so that it runs the CMD as the main container process is a generally useful pattern.  If you don't then standard debugging tricks like `docker run --rm -it imagename /bin/sh` don't work.

Comment: Thanks - adding `php-fpm` to the end of the script has done the job.